# SQLite3 is not creating a database, only giving an error. Why?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a database with SQLite3 but each time I run `sqlite3 test.db` it just takes me onto a new line and no database is created. I assumed I had to add a table to the database as well so I created one and once done it just says `Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error`. So creating a table to complete the database creation was not the issue. I have searched all over the web and each resource is telling me to do the same thing I have been doing that only results in an error. If this is the same syntax all other online resources are using successfully, why is it constantly failing to create a database for me?

Here is a screenshot of the exact attempt:
[image]

Comment: Please show the exact commands you used, and highlight what is or is not working.

Comment: Do you have the sqlite3 shell installed on this computer and in your path?

Comment: @Shawn I checked on the sqlite3 website when initially getting sqlite3 and there were no downloads for the shell. I only downloaded the sqlite dll and sqlite tools files.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please see the screenshot I attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the order/placement of commands mixed up.  From the *folder* containing SQLite on your system, you should create a database via `sqlite3 somedb.db`:

```
C:\path\to\sqlite>sqlite3 test.db;
sqlite>           <-- prompt lets you know that you have connected
```

Once you have connected to that database, you don't need to specify it again for operations intended against that database.  So, I expect the following `CREATE TABLE` statement to work:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test.testtbl (
   ...> col1 text,
   ...> col2 text,
   ...> col3 text);
```

Comment: But the issue is that the database itself is not even creating to begin with. It looks like the first word in the command just keeps causing an error to occur.

Comment: Does `test.db` already exist, and did you do _exactly_ what my answer suggests?

Comment: Yes I did. From what I've read on, the database should be created and stored in the same folder sqlite3 is running from when created (correct me if I'm wrong). But when I enter `.databases` into the console, no databases come up and `test.db` is not present in my sqlite3 folder.

Comment: Then you should either edit this question or ask a new one.  The question you asked is about `CREATE TABLE` not working.  But the real problem is that you don't really have a database.

Comment: The heading clearly states it's about sqlite3 not creating a database, but nonetheless I've edited accordingly in the details.

Comment: The screen capture in your question indicates that you did _not_ do the steps in my answer.  `sqlite3 test.db` needs to be run _outside_ of the SQLite program, in the folder where SQLite is.  Look closely at your output: `Connected to a transient in-memory database.`

Comment: Okay now I understand. So after reading your last comment, I went into normal command prompt, changed the file path command prompt was set on to my SQLite folder, then ran `sqlite3 test.db` and it created the database successfully. Thanks :)